# Telegram Bot method getupdates too slow and not all json result? Why?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

This is a very simple code of a getupdates method for a Telegram Bot.

```
 <?php
 $update=file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot206686165:AAH59jwJZDPhrY7r-0jL3qEWJkKjTTmXUUo/getupdates");
 print_r($update);   ?>
```

now the result is loaded very slow(20 sec) and is not all/right -Why this?:

> {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":103868812,
>   "message":{"message_id":5,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462527792,"text":"/start","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":6}]}},{"update_id":103868813,
>   "message":{"message_id":6,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462527794,"text":"ciao"}},{"update_id":103868814,
>   "message":{"message_id":7,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Rob

The result by only link:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot'MY_TOKEN'/getupdates
```

is fast and is this:

> {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":103868812,
>   "message":{"message_id":5,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462527792,"text":"/start","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":6}]}},{"update_id":103868813,
>   "message":{"message_id":6,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462527794,"text":"ciao"}},{"update_id":103868814,
>   "message":{"message_id":7,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462527824,"text":"/ciao","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":5}]}},{"update_id":103868815,
>   "message":{"message_id":8,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462527826,"text":"/ciao","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":5}]}},{"update_id":103868816,
>   "message":{"message_id":9,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462527826,"text":"/ciao","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":5}]}},{"update_id":103868817,
>   "message":{"message_id":10,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462527826,"text":"/ciao","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":5}]}},{"update_id":103868818,
>   "message":{"message_id":11,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462527826,"text":"/ciao","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":5}]}},{"update_id":103868819,
>   "message":{"message_id":12,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462528498,"text":"/start","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":6}]}},{"update_id":103868820,
>   "message":{"message_id":13,"from":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono"},"chat":{"id":56277261,"first_name":"Roberto","last_name":"D'Antuono","type":"private"},"date":1462528503,"text":"mamma"}}]}

Can you help me for this? my domain is on altervista.org and you try this link for test slow load...

http://unisadb.altervista.org/BOT/hello.php

Answer (score 0):

When you call it by link, you are connecting to Telegram server from your computer. run the code on your local computer and check the result. I think the problem is with your server and the connection between your server and Telegram's is slow.